# SAS: Insert a value into a macro variable from connection to ODBC

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get DDL from Redshift tables' catalog.

Using the below method is the only way I know to insert a value into a macro variable.

```
 proc sql noprint;
connect to odbc(&_OUTPUT_connect.);
  SELECT ddl into :a trimmed from connection to ODBC
            ( SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' + n.nspname + '.' + c.relname + ' AS\n' + COALESCE(pg_get_viewdef(c.oid, TRUE), '') AS ddl
              FROM 
              pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
              INNER JOIN
              pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n
              ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
             WHERE n.nspname||'.'||c.relname in ('ditemp.depend_test1' ,'ditemp.depend_test2' ,'ditemp.depend_test3','ditemp.depend_test4')
             );     
disconnect from odbc;                
quit;
```

But it doesn't work (hangs).

Are there any other method to do the above?

Comment: If you select it into a table, are you getting the expected results?

Comment: No, I only get the expected result querying SAS' object metadata (not using pass through). The reason I'm not using this method is, in DI, library doesn't seem to be assigned automatically and I can't put a hardcoded Libname statement in code

Comment: Oh, that SQL statement is a command to create/replace a view, it doesn't actually return any results.  There's nothing for it to store into a macro variable.

Comment: I am not sure why? I just generate DDL, put in a column called DDL and try to insert it into a macro variable...

Comment: Is it because you are mixing up your concatenation operators?  In your where clause you are using `||` but in your select clause you are using `+`.

Comment: This code on its own works okay on the Redshift client. It even works (although does nothing) when execute from DI. Only when I add the Select Into it hangs.

Comment: What data type is the result going to be?  Perhaps it you cast it to a type that you are sure SAS can support?

Comment: Try `separated by ' '` instead of `trimmed`.  Maybe SAS and ODBC are getting confused about how many records are to be returned?